# Page not found(404) - polls views django tutorial

Tags: python, django, django-templates, http-status-404

Estou fazendo o tutorial da documentação do Django, na parte 3 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial03/) onde é dito depois de adicionar alguns códigos o seguinte:

> "Take a look in your browser, at “/polls/34/”. It’ll run the detail()
> method and display whatever ID you provide in the URL. Try
> “/polls/34/results/” and “/polls/34/vote/” too – these will display
> the placeholder results and voting pages."

O problema é que ao acessar http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/34/, eu recebo o erro:

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/34/
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
polls/ [name='index']
The current path, polls/34/, didn't match any of these.

ja revisei o código zilhões de vezes, e to me frustrando...

settings.py

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
```

mysite/urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

polls/views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World. You're at the polls index.")


def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)


def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)


def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

por que não ta funcionando???

se estiver faltando algum código por favor me avise .

**Att: descobri que o problema é no Pycharm, já que no vs code funcionou tudo certinho, o problema pode ser a versão de python sendo utilizada?**

Answer (score 2):

O seu último código está mesmo em polls.models? Se sim, é aí que está o erro. Você precisa criar uma arquivo chamado 'urls.py' dentro do app 'polls'. É dessa maneira que o urls.py do seu projeto incluirá o 'polls.urls' (confira no segundo pedaço de código que você postou).

Comment: coloquei o nome da pasta errada, ja arrumei na pergunta, obrigado... sim ja estava em urls.py dentro de polls ...

Comment: Eu copiei e colei no VS code o código que você disponibilizou na pergunta, rodei o server e tudo deu certo, inclusive o polls/34. O erro não está no código, mas provavelmente em alguma das etapas da configuração, ou em nomes de arquivos. Verifique se você registrou o app no settings.py/INSTALLED_APPS; verifique também se você rodou o manage.py migrate corretamente. Se nada der certo, crie um novo projeto e copie e cole o código que você mesmo postou aqui. Eu fiz isso e funcionou. Espero que dê certo.

Comment: quando entro em /admin e /polls as pages funcionam corretamente, se o problema fosse em INSTALLED_APPS iria funcionar? Digo, essas 3 pages derivadas de polls não deveriam funcionar apenas com 'polls.apps.PollsConfig' lá? 

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Atualizando aqui, antes utilizavao Pycharm para rodar, agora utilizando o VScode deu certo ...